# Add to list functionality in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and trying to implement add to list functionality. I have a few questions

1. why does `console.log` of `$scope.newChat` return *undefined*
2. Is `newChat` available to `sendChat()` call due to variable hoisting.

**Template**

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}" >
        <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item >
        <form ng-submit="sendChat(newchat)"> <!-- this line in question 2 -->
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="newchat.lastText">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-right button-positive">Send</button>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**controller**

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
  $scope.sendChat = function(newchat){
    Chats.set(newchat);
    console.log($scope.newchat); //this line in question 1
    newchat.lastText  = "";
  }
})
```

Comment: What is `Chats.set`? The implementation of `.set` method is imperative for your question

Comment: ion-item creates a new scope. And you have not initialized newchat in your controller scope, so it will create newchat at ion-item level. So you can't access it through your controller scope. So if you want to access newchat in your controller scope, create empty newchat object in your controller scope. Then it will be shared by ion-item. And you will have it in your controller scope.

Comment: @dhavalcengg plz submit your comment as answer so that i can mark it as correct answer

Comment: @aWebDeveloper I have added my comment as answer, now you can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

> 1) why does console.log of $scope.newChat return undefined

you are  getting newchat on scope `console.log($scope.newchat);` try console logging with `console.log(newchat);` they both are same as newchat in ng-model make it available on scope. See console after clicking send button in demo below

> 2)Is newChat available to sendChat() call due to variable hoisting.

No it is available due to ng-model data binding

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope) {
  //$scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    //Chats.remove(chat);
  }
  $scope.sendChat = function(newchat){
   // Chats.set(newchat);
    console.log($scope.newchat); //this line in question 1
    newchat.lastText  = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ChatsCtrl"> <form ng-submit="sendChat(newchat)"> <!-- this line in question 2 -->
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="newchat.lastText">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-right button-positive">Send</button>
            </label>
         
        </form>
     
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your controller to following

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.newchat = {};
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
  $scope.sendChat = function(newchat){
    Chats.set(newchat);
    console.log($scope.newchat); //now you will have your $scope.newchat
    newchat.lastText  = "";
  }
})
```